# Convert JSON array and keys to JSON dict

Tags: json, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I've noticed that some APIs use a format of sending a stripped down version of their data via a JSON array like the following:

```
[
  "joe",
  [
    5,
    2,
    "yellow"
  ]
]
```

And store a set of keys like the following:

```
[
  "name",
  ["some_data", [
    "favorite_number",
    "least_favorite_number",
    "car_color"
  ]]
]
```

To turn the data from a bunch of random values to a readable set of data, like the following:

```
{
  "name": "joe",
  "some_data": {
    "favorite_number": 5,
    "least_favorite_number": 2,
    "car_color": "yellow"
  }
}
```

I was wondering how this could be done? I'd prefer it'd be in python, but I'm fine with programming my own libraries.

Answer (score 0):

After grasping at more straws than I could fit in my mouth, I've figured it out. JSON schema is what I'm supposed to be using!